# Javascript close a toggle using a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to show and hide content using only javascript, html and css. I have been able to get button to show and hide information on the page but am unable to get the close button to hide the information.

```js
"use strict";
// /*Show Nutritional information results*/
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".contentButton");
for (const b of buttons) {
  b.addEventListener('click', ev => {
    ev.target.classList.toggle("on");
  })
}
```

```css
.contentButton {
  background-color: #008CBA;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.contentButton.on+div {
  display: block;
}

.content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 10% auto;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h2>Item List</h2>
<div class="Item1">
  <button class="contentButton">toggle</button>
  <div class="content">loooaads of stuff goes here</div>
  <button class="close">Close</button>
</div>

<div class="Item2">
  <button class="contentButton">toggle</button>
  <div class="content">stuff goes here</div>
  <button class="close">Close</button>
</div>

<div class="Item3">
  <button class="contentButton">toggle</button>
  <div class="content">mooooreeee stuff goes here</div>
  <button class="close">Close</button>
</div>

<div class="Item4">
  <button class="contentButton">toggle</button>
  <div class="content">stuff goes here</div>
  <button class="close">Close</button>
</div>

<div class="Item5">
  <button class="contentButton">toggle</button>
  <div class="content">stuff goes here</div>
  <button class="close">Close</button>
</div>

<div class="Item1">
  <button class="contentButton">toggle</button>
  <div class="content">stuff goes here</div>
  <button class="close">Close</button>
</div>
```

Can someone please help so that the close button hides the content when it is open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would move the `on` class up to be relative to the content parent.

```css
div[class^="Item"].on div.content,
div[class^="Item"].on button.close {
  display: block;
}

div.content,
button.close {
  display: none;
}
```

Then all you need to do is get the target button's parent and toggle the class.

If you can, I would add an additional class to all the items that they can be identified easier in CSS.

```css
div.expandable-content.on div.content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="expandable-content Item1">
  <button class="contentButton">toggle</button>
  <div class="content">loooaads of stuff goes here</div>
  <button class="close">Close</button>
</div>
<!-- ...etc -->
```

---

### Example

```js
const queryAll = (selector) => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector))

const showContent = (button, visible) => {
  button.parentElement.classList.toggle('on', visible)
}

queryAll(".contentButton").forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', e => {
    showContent(e.target, true)
  })
})

queryAll(".close").forEach(closeBtn => {
  closeBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
    showContent(e.target, false)
  })
})
```

```css
.contentButton {
  background-color: #008CBA;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

div[class^="Item"].on div.content {
  display: block;
}

div[class^="Item"].on button.close {
  display: block;
}

.close {
  display: none;
}

.content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 10% auto;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h2>Item List</h2>
<div class="Item1">
  <button class="contentButton">toggle</button>
  <div class="content">loooaads of stuff goes here</div>
  <button class="close">Close</button>
</div>

<div class="Item2">
  <button class="contentButton">toggle</button>
  <div class="content">stuff goes here</div>
  <button class="close">Close</button>
</div>

<div class="Item3">
  <button class="contentButton">toggle</button>
  <div class="content">mooooreeee stuff goes here</div>
  <button class="close">Close</button>
</div>

<div class="Item4">
  <button class="contentButton">toggle</button>
  <div class="content">stuff goes here</div>
  <button class="close">Close</button>
</div>

<div class="Item5">
  <button class="contentButton">toggle</button>
  <div class="content">stuff goes here</div>
  <button class="close">Close</button>
</div>

<div class="Item1">
  <button class="contentButton">toggle</button>
  <div class="content">stuff goes here</div>
  <button class="close">Close</button>
</div>
```

---

With the close button embedded, you need to get the content (parent) for the button, before you can get the wrapping div (grandparent).

```js
const queryAll = (selector) => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector))

const showContent = (button, visible) => {
  button.parentElement.classList.toggle('on', visible)
}

queryAll(".contentButton").forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', e => {
    showContent(e.target, true)
  })
})

queryAll(".close").forEach(closeBtn => {
  closeBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
    showContent(e.target.parentElement, false)
  })
})
```

```css
.contentButton {
  background-color: #008CBA;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

div[class^="Item"].on div.content {
  display: block;
}

div[class^="Item"].on button.close {
  display: block;
}

.close {
  display: none;
}

.content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 10% auto;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h2>Item List</h2>
<div class="Item1">
  <button class="contentButton">toggle</button>
  <div class="content">
    loooaads of stuff goes here
    <button class="close">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="Item2">
  <button class="contentButton">toggle</button>
  <div class="content">
    stuff goes here
    <button class="close">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="Item3">
  <button class="contentButton">toggle</button>
  <div class="content">
    mooooreeee stuff goes here
    <button class="close">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="Item4">
  <button class="contentButton">toggle</button>
  <div class="content">
    stuff goes here
    <button class="close">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="Item5">
  <button class="contentButton">toggle</button>
  <div class="content">
    stuff goes here
    <button class="close">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="Item1">
  <button class="contentButton">toggle</button>
  <div class="content">
    stuff goes here
    <button class="close">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this it works well! If I wanted to put the close button in the contents div it stops working though. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: You need to remove the parent specification for the close button. I will update it.

Comment: @LaurentKosci Do you want the close button literally inside the content div?

Comment: Yes Please inside the  <div class="content">stuff goes here</div>

Comment: @LaurentKosci Added to the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".contentButton");
const closebtns = document.querySelectorAll(".close");
  for (const b of buttons) {
    b.addEventListener('click', ev => {
      ev.target.classList.toggle("on");
    })
  }  
  for (const c of closebtns) {
    c.addEventListener('click', ev => {
      ev.target.closest("div").querySelector(".contentButton").classList.toggle("on");
    })
  }
```

**Explanation:**

- `document.querySelectorAll(".close")` get all close buttons and add click event listener to all of them.
- `ev.target.closest("div")` get the [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) div to the current clicked close button.
- `closest("div").querySelector(".contentButton")` - find the `contentButton` inside the parent div and toggle the class `on` on that element.

Comment: Hey thanks for this it works well! If I wanted to put the close button in the contents div it stops working though. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: You can try: `ev.target.closest('[class^="Item"]').querySelector(".contentButton").classList.toggle("on");`